# Does Watch Dogs feature Bruce Wayne?

Tags: watch-dogs

I know that the Watch Dogs is set in the city of Chicago, not Gotham, but I saw at some site the profile of Bruce Wayne with $20 billion dollars in his bank account in some random street in Watch Dogs.

So the question is: does Bruce Wayne really exist in Watch Dogs or this is a hoax?

If it's true, did someone find where he hangs out?

Here is a picture showing this:

[image: as in the Batman Bruce Wayne]

Comment: No, no, no. Income != money in your bank account. That is his *annual income*; some of it goes to the IRS, some into *banks* and other investments (no body in their right mind would put that much into ***a*** bank - the FDIC only insures you for $100,000) but since he is Batman, the majority of it is extorted by his butler for hush money to keep his identity secret and the rest goes to insuring the bat mobile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a civilian profile for "Bruce, Wayne", but this is just an Easter egg. Neither the real Bruce Wayne nor Batman are actually in the game. It is just the game *playing a joke on you*, making it a [hoax](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=hoax%20definition).

[image]

Comment: so its just a hoax?

Comment: **+1**: The very notion of a "real Bruce Wayne" gave me a chuckle.

Comment: The definition of hoax is: "a humorous or malicious deception". I will edit my post to make it more clear. The verb hoax can also mean "to play a practical joke on".

Answer (score 8):

The bat is a lie. The only thing I can find about this is a video on YouTube, which is fake. There's a Wayne Bruce who's into BDSM, but there's no Bruce Wayne millionaire vigilante.

Comment: Maybe he is in our hearts.